# Reading a binary file into byte array

Tags: java, arrays, binary, binaryfiles, readfile

I need to read a binary file and save each byte into a byte array. I've read other stackoverflow posts on this topic, but cannot figure out why mine does not work. Here is what I have:

```
String fileOne = "file1.bin";
byte[] byteArray = new byte[1000];
try{
    FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(fileOne);
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fileIS);
    is.read(byteArray);
    is.close();
    for(int i =0; i < byteArray.length; i++){
        System.out.println(byteArray[i]);
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    e.toString();
    System.exit(0);
}
catch (IOException io){
    io.toString();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: "save each bit as a byte" - Each *bit* or each *byte*? To read bytes from a file, use `Files#readAllBytes`.

Comment: If I use readAllBytes(); how do I save these into byte array? @JacobG.

Comment: The method returns a `byte[]`.

Comment: Try replacing your `catch` block to catch any exceptions, not just the two you're currently catching. This will help expose any hidden exceptions. So just catch `Exception`.

Comment: Do you really want to convert each byte into eight bytes of one bit each?  That is what you said.

Comment: No, I apologize I edited the post to be correct @WJS.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to read the contents of a file into a `byte` array. `FileInputStream` is all you need – leave `ObjectInputStream` out of it (unless you are explicitly dealing with data that was *created* from an `ObjectOutputStream`, but that doesn't seem to be the case since you are calling `println()` on each byte).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "file1.bin";
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
        byte[] bytes = fis.readAllBytes();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

A few things here:

- omit using `ObjectInputStream` – not needed for reading byte data, and won't work unless the data was created by the corresponding output stream. From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html): *"An ObjectInputStream deserializes primitive data and objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream. "*
- use `try` with resources – it will close the associated stream for you
- catch `Exception` – in the code you posted, you will only see info if `FileNotFoundException` or `IOException` is thrown. For anything else, your code doesn't handle them or print out any info.